# What set would contain a bag of mixed white and light gray peices?

Tags: set-identification

This bag only contains white and light gray LEGO pieces with a deep white door and window.

What set does it belong to?

[image: bag of mixed elements, all white and light gray]

Answer (score 1):

This belongs to the set [10698 Large Creative Brick Box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10698-1)

[image]

Key parts:

Newer fence 1x4x2 (15332) in White

1x6x2 arch (12939) in LBG

2x4 brick (3001) in LBG